# python subploting in a loop, only the first subplot is shown

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I am experiencing subplotting in a loop. I failed to plot with using below code. The bottom subplot is empty

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex = True)

for n in range(2):
    ax[n].plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

the failed plot looks like this. Any thoughts?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Also, `range(0,1)` is only one item (`[0]` if converted to a list)

Comment: Hi Sayse, it is just an example. The problem is the loop does not work. The bottom subplot has nothing.

Comment: Hi @Sayse thank you for your swift response, I revised my code, and it is still not working. the new code gives the same empty bottom subplot

Comment: can't reproduce, this works for me

Comment: `for n in range(2):
    ax[n].plot(x,y)`    Try to use this

Comment: @JoshFriedlander thank you for your response, I tried again, it still does not work in my environment, l think it might be something related to python version?

Comment: Are you running the above *precise* code in a standalone script?

Comment: @9769953 yes! but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Of course not: there is no import there, so you're not running that exact code. Sorry to be pedantic about that, but if we're not 100% sure you're running the exact same code, standalone (i.e., not in a notebook with all kind of things defined), things are hard to debug.

Comment: I see an IPython interface, with a number of unknown (to us) commands before that. You may want to restart that completely if possible, to have a clean slate. Or run your script in an (external) terminal.

Comment: Move `plt.show()` *outside* the for loop.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Note: your edits unfortunately corrected the mistake by the OP, so there was no problem. Until the OP corrected your mistake: indentation is finicky with Python. This definitely caused some confusion above in the comments.

Comment: @9769953 someone in the comment asked OP to move it inside the loop. At first, it was okay.

Comment: @SanjuHalder That has nothing to do with the edit, and was an incorrect suggestion. It was not ok before, check the edit history.

Comment: @9769953 at third edit, OP corrected the indentation.  That what I was trying to say by 'first'. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `plt.show()` *outside* the for loop:

```
for n in range(2):
    ax[n].plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Elizabeth The unfortunate part was that someone edited your question, in particular the code block, and along the way, accidentally fixed your issue. They should have paid more attention, and ask for clarification first, but I guess that's how things go. It just made it take longer to provide the solution, with additional confusion along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you wanted it to be ??

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex = True)
for n in range(2):
    ax[n].plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

output:
[image]

Comment: yes, this is what I want, but it just doesn't work in my environment. I uploaded a screenshot, I really can't tell what is wrong...